# How to interpret coefficient estimate from a zero inflation model?

Tags: r, zero-inflation

gling with the interpretation of the coefficients of a zero-inflation model and I find no clear answer in the net. Maybe someone can help me and other people in the same situation.

After fitting cancer incidences through a Poisson regression with zero-inflation (zeroinfl package in R), in the logistic component, the coefficient estimate for the age variable is -3.6.

Does that mean that for each additional year of age, the odds of having zero cancer incidences increases by 3.6, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

First of all a zero-inflated component does not model the odds of zeroes, it models the odds of $structural$ zeroes.

It means that for every additional year of age the log odds of seeing being in the structural zero group (those who cannot have cancer) decrease with 3.6 . On the level of the odds this means a decrease by a factor

$$\exp(-3.6) = 0.027$$